# Sqlalchemy with Flask - deleted data is still shown

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

## Description

I have an Flask application with original SQLalchemy. Application is intended to be used internally in a company for easier saving of measurement data with MySQL

On one page I have a table with all devices used for measurement and a form that is used to add, remove or modify measurement devices.

## Problem

The problem is that when I enter a new device in the database, the page is automatically refreshed to fetch new data from DB and new device is sometimes shown and sometimes it is not when I refresh the page. In other words, added row in table is appearing and dissapearing even though the row is visible on database. Same goes when i try to delete the device from database. The row is sometimes shown, sometimes not when refreshing the page with row being deleted from DB.
The same problem appears for all examples similar to this one (adding, deleting and modifying data).

## What i have tried

Bellow is the code for table model:

```
class DvDevice(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dvdevice"

    id = Column("device_id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column("device_name", String(50), nullable=True)
    code = Column("device_code", String(10), nullable=True, unique=True)
    hw_ver = Column("hw_ver", String(10), nullable=True)
    fw_ver = Column("fw_ver", String(10), nullable=True)
    sw_ver = Column("sw_ver", String(10), nullable=True)
```

And here is the code that inserts/deletes data from table.

```
    #Insertion
    device = DvDevice()
    device.code = self.device_code
    device.name = self.device_name
    device.hw_ver = self.hw_ver
    device.fw_ver = self.fw_ver
    device.sw_ver = self.sw_ver
    ses.add(device)
    ses.commit()
    ses.expire_all() #Should this be here?

    # Deletion
    ses.query(DvDevice).filter_by(id=self.device_id).delete()
    ses.commit()
    ses.expire_all() # Should this be here?
```

I have read from some posts on stack to include the following decorator function in models.py

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
   ses.expire_all() #ses being database session object.
```

I tried this and it still doesn't work as it should be. Should I put the decorator function somewhere else?

Second thing i tried is to put `ses.expire_all()` after all commits and it still doesnt work.

What should I do to prevent this from happening?

## Edit 1

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, update
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

from config import MYSQLCONNECT

engine = create_engine(MYSQLCONNECT)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()
```

Comment: Please include how `ses` is defined. Is it a scoped session? `ses.expire_all()` during teardown is not enough, especially with MySQL, since MySQL's default transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ. If your transactions continue from request to request, you'll observe that some requests may see data that others don't and the other way around. So: always begin and end your transactions with the request handling, not just when you make changes.

Comment: I updated the question.
I dont completely understand the "always begin and end your transactions with the request handling, not just when you make changes".

Comment: Always commit or rollback during teardown, possibly close/remove the session (in order to return connections to the pool). If your edit is all you have, and you're using a threaded server to serve requests, you'll run to a different set of issues as well. A `Session` is not thread safe.

Comment: So i should close the session after every request and start another one before commiting again the next time?
The server has 2 web workers. Like I said, its going to be run internally on one maybe two computers. Is that going to be a problem?

Comment: A good read: ["When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it) and ["Is the session thread-safe?"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe). I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "web worker", so the latter may or may not apply.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. You could btw. self-answer too, so perhaps the next person in the same situation can find help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with the use of following function from http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()



with session_scope() as session:
    ... # code that uses session
```

The problem was that I created the session object in the beggining and then never closed it.